# Using multicolumn with landscape

Tags: tables, multicolumn, landscape, booktabs

[image]Hello,

I am trying to make a table in landscape form, which should have the layout like the one presented in the image. However, I seem to be doing something wrong with the multicolumn command, and with ending the document.

The code is attached below.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Kusha

```
  \documentclass[10.5pt,a4]{article}
   \usepackage[margin=0.5in,a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption}
   \usepackage{capt-of}
   \usepackage{longtable}
  \usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
  \newcommand\mceight[1]{\multicolumn{13}{l}{#1}}
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \usepackage{afterpage}

  \widowpenalty500
  \clubpenalty500
 \clubpenalty=9996
  \exhyphenpenalty=50 %for line-breaking at an explicit hyphen
  \brokenpenalty=4991
  \predisplaypenalty=10000
 \postdisplaypenalty=1549
 \displaywidowpenalty=1602
 \floatingpenalty = 20000
 \usepackage{siunitx}

 \begin{document}
 \afterpage
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
    \centering
      \begin{table}[ht] \centering
\begin{small}
\begin{tabular}{ l*{13}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
\toprule
\thead[b]{Dependant Variable : log(hourly wages)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Percentiles} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-10}
\\
\thead[b]{Independent Variables} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10th} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{30th} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{50th} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{70th} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{90th} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{OLS} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-11}\cmidrule(lr){12-13}
  & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff}  & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat} \\
   Constant & 1.107 & 9.96 & 1.606 & 20.07 & 1.859 & 26.76 & 2.095 & 29.12 & 2.642 & 28.94 & 1.740 & 27.51 \\
    Gender & 0.542 & 23.7 & 0.503 & 30.1 & 0.480 & 33.24 & 0.418 & 27.28 & 0.309 & 15.99 & 0.443 & 33.33 \\
     Age & 0.007 & 7.22 & 0.013 & 16.91 & 0.015 & 23.98 & 0.017 & 25.24 & 0.016 & 18.71 & 0.017 & 28.26 \\
     Urban & 0.232 & 13.07 & 0.196 & 15.13 & 0.168 & 15.01 & 0.168 & 14.18 & 0.168 & 11.23 & 0.211 & 20.5 \\
 \end{tabular}
 \end{small}
 \end{table}
 \captionof{table}{Quantile regression results}% Add 'table' caption
 \end{landscape}
 \clearpage% Flush page
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You have to many & between the multicolumns, and you should add braces around the {coeff} and the {t-stat} to protect them from the S-column-type.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, that makes sense. I just did the edits, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

- based on my answer on your previous question
- added package `multirow`
- `small` is not environment but toggle command, so it is suficient to write just `\small`
- document class `article` doesn't recognize font size `10.5`
- a4 option is not valid. paper size you have defined in options of `geometry`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
\newcommand\mctwelve[1]{\multicolumn{12}{c}{#1}}% :-)
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
 \afterpage{\clearpage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
    \centering
\begin{table}[ht] \centering
    \small
\begin{tabular}{ l*{12}{S[table-format=2.3]} }
    \toprule
\thead[b]{Dependant Variable:\\ log(hourly wages)}
    & \mctwelve{\thead{Percentiles}}                                \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-13}      
\multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Independent\\ Variables}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10th}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{30th}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{50th}
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{70th}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{90th}
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{OLS}                   \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-11}\cmidrule(lr){12-13}
    & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat}
    & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat}  \\
    \midrule
Constant
    & 1.107   & 9.96     & 1.606   & 20.07    & 1.859   & 26.76
    & 2.095   & 29.12    & 2.642   & 28.94    & 1.740   & 27.51     \\
Gender
    & 0.542   & 23.7     & 0.503   & 30.1     & 0.480   & 33.24
    & 0.418   & 27.28    & 0.309   & 15.99    & 0.443   & 33.33     \\
Age & 0.007   & 7.22     & 0.013   & 16.91    & 0.015   & 23.98
    & 0.017   & 25.24    & 0.016   & 18.71    & 0.017   & 28.26     \\
Urban
    & 0.232   & 13.07    & 0.196   & 15.13    & 0.168   & 15.01
    & 0.168   & 14.18    & 0.168   & 11.23    & 0.211   & 20.5      \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Quantile regression results}% Add 'table' caption
    \label{tab:mylandscapetable}% or whatewer
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: you have been a saviour today! The only remaining struggle is with \longtable :p