# How to combine a pdflscape table with multicols (or alternative)?

Tags: tables, multicol, landscape

I am using the multicols package combined with inputs (cf. \input{inputs/abstract}) to load in different latex parts. Now my document requires a horizontal table but I can't get it to work.

I have tried to use the pdflscape package but couldn't get it to work. I am aware of [Using multicolumn with landscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387366/using-multicolumn-with-landscape). I have not tried to use the rotation package or sidewaystable yet because people have a strong opinion on craning their necks.

I have cut into my code to make a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}       % Required by Babel
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1.6in, left=1.20in, bottom=1.7in, right=1.2in]{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e} %Better text alignment
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx} % Table width i.c.w. the multicolumn width
\usepackage{graphicx} %includes figures
\usepackage{pdflscape} %For a landscape table


\begin{document}
    % \input{sections/preper}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        % Several inputs omitted
        \input{sections/analysis}        
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

With the analysis being

```
\section{Analysis}
% Some text

\begin{landscape}
\subsection{Table}
    \begin{figure*}[ht]
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
          \hline
          Column & Column & Column & Column & Column & Column & Column \\\hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{figure*}
\end{landscape}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why don't you end the `multicols` environment before the landscape table and begin a new one after it?

Comment: @cabobah The reason is that the compiler can't handle the `\begin{multicols}{2}` outside the `\input{...}` and `\end{multicols}{2}`inside it. Using the multicols-environment inside each input instead of outside it gives a illegible text order (then two columned sections are appended instead of the entire document being split in two columns)